# Console-based Key Listener Java

Tags: java, console, key, ascii, listener

I am trying to write a small text-based game in Java. I had previously written this in C++, but I used "getch()" in C++, and I have no idea what the java equivalent. I am fairly new, and so am not very experienced, but I am able to learn. Is there a Java equivalent to "getch()" in Java? It needs to return the ASCII value of the key. Ideas?

Comment: ASCII is probably not very useful, as Java works on UTF-16 internally.

Comment: @nfechner I would like to use ASCII because I have already coded in the ASCII values. I can also just assign an integer the values, i.e. when someone presses the esc key, then the integer will have a value of 27. That is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [BufferedReader](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html&ei=TS1EUoLSMYXJrQfW5YGQAw&usg=AFQjCNGKo0sohY-ojpUjooopThDDhsDLBQ&bvm=bv.53217764,d.bmk) to replicate getch()

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class myclass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Press Enter to continue");
        try 
        {
            int ascii = br.read();
            System.out.println("ASCII Value - "+ascii);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Output

```
Enter any character to continue
<press a then hit Enter>
ASCII Value - 97
```

Comment: This should really say "Press enter to continue". It does not work with "any key".

Comment: I needed something that would give the ASCII value to the characters pressed. Any way to do that?

Comment: Check the changes in the code, but you would have to press enter after entering a character. The program outputs the ASCII value of the character entered

Answer (score 0):

In general, you read input from System.in.  You can read from this stream in lots of ways, but one option is to use java.util.scanner.

Try something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
byte mybyte = keyboard.nextByte();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @space55 if you want it to register as soon as you press a button without hitting enter, I don't think it's possible in Java. After all, the java program does not own the console window. The console is not a java application, java just interacts with it, passing output to it, and receiving input from it.

Comment: The compiler Eclipse from Oracle

Comment: @Cruncher Is there any way I could convert this to a graphics version? I'll place the source code+launch file on Github.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use

```
InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
int charValue = inStream.read();
```

then switch on the character value from there.

As someone else mentioned, Java works on UTF-16, but for characters [a-zA-z0-9] and normal punctuation, you won't notice a difference.

Javadoc for the InputStreamReader: [InputStreamReader Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read%28%29)

Comment: You've forgotten both of the semicolons

Comment: It's giving me a red underline on the area of the second "InputStreamReader"

Comment: @Cruncher System.in.read() returns a byte value, or in the case of other read methods, a byte[].  This gives him the option of getting a char[], and avoiding a cast if he wants.  Could go either way.  (fixed missing 'new')

Comment: InputStreamReader and System.in.read both need Enter to be pressed.

Comment: Forgot the new before the second InputStreamReader